# Java client/server - sum of 2 numbers using AWT

Tags: java, awt, client-server

This is the exercise I got stuck with:

I have to use AWT text fields to insert two integers, and clicking on a button to print their sum. Parsing both values and sum calculation need to be done on the server side, and then to be sent back to the client.
How do I return a result? Did I choose a right approach?! Here is what I've done, so if anyone can help and give some suggestion I would be grateful.

Server code:

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String args []) throws IOException{


    try (ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1342);
        Socket ss1 = s1.accept();
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss1.getInputStream()));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(ss1.getOutputStream());
        ){

            int res = 0;
            String line = b.readLine();
            while(line != null && !line.equals("")){
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());
                res = num1 + num2;



            }
            bos.write((res+"").getBytes()); 
     }
   } 
}
```

and this is a client code, written under the button action event:

```
private void calculate_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
   try (
       Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1342);           
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
       BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ){
       // num1 and num2 are text fields
       bos.write((num1.getText()).getBytes()); 
       bos.write((num2.getText()).getBytes());
       bos.flush();


       String res = br.readLine();
       while (res != null){
           res=br.readLine();
       result.setText(res);  // label where result should be printed
       }           


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SumUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: Ok, I've done it now... @Andrew Thompson

Comment: Good edit!  Noise deleted..